# Select options disappearing when appending new option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I'm currently creating a interface to select an option from one select element on double click, and append it to another select element.

The issue I am coming across is when doing so, it is added and visible, however all other options disappear in the destination select, until I click on the option and then click off.

You can see this in action here: https://i.imgur.com/jSXoIAi.gifv

My current implementation is as follows:

```
$('body').on('dblclick', '#availableColumnsSelect > option', function (e) {

        var option = $(this);

        //Add option to destination
        displayColumnsSelect.append($('<option>', { value: option.val(), text: option.val() }));

        //Remove option from source
        option.remove();


        //Sort the select options
        sortSelect("#displayColumnsSelect");


        var optionsAvailable = $("#availableColumnsSelect > option:not([disabled])").length;


        if (optionsAvailable == 0) {
            $("#noSelectedText").removeClass('hidden');
        }
        $("#noSelectedText").addClass('hidden');
});
```

The underlying HTML is being constructed exactly how it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing here would remove any options from the destination list.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: BTW, instead of creating a new option and removing the old one, you can just move it: `displayColumnsSelect.append(option)`

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `sortSelect()`.

Comment: I had the same problem and got a pretty good answer. Although part of it was "file a bug with the browser vendors..." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61545958/disappearing-elements-when-moving-options-between-select-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out the issue was with the sortSelection function. I'm not quite sure why, but regardless I don't actually require this function anymore.

Removing said function has resolved the issue :)